# What happens when LockType.READ method is called by LockType.Write method

Tags: java, concurrency, session-bean

What happens when a LockType WRITE method in a singleton, container managed session bean which is of LockType READ at class level calls another method within the same bean which is of LockType READ.

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class EmployeBean implements Employee {

  @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
  public Employee update() {
   //update 
  }

  public void calculate () {
    //calculate and set 
  }
}
```

With the above bean, is it correct to have an implementation like this? What happens when this update() is being executed and at the same time some other service calls the calculate() ? Will the service wait until update() finishes or it also executes calculate() in parallel?I believe if it does go on in parallel it has high chances of corrupting the data or ending in data mismatch.

The calculate method can be made private and use only under a WRITE protected method. That way it is made sure there cannot be mismatch because of concurrent requests.

Wanted to know the impact and follow correct approach in handling concurrent requests in case like the above.

Comment: ["If a method is of locking type WRITE, client access to all the singleton’s methods is blocked until the current client finishes its method call or an access timeout occurs."](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html)

Comment: I misinterpreted  that it locks only access to that method instead of the bean. Thanks it is clear now.